# Why is it possible to access form values in the inline event handler?

Tags: javascript, html

[I just realized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57047920/3779853) that inside a form event handler (like `onsubmit` or `oninput` etc), you can access control values globally, meaning the following does indeed work:

```html
<form onsubmit="alert(theInput.value); return false">
  <input name="theInput">
</form>
```

Why does this work? I never defined `theInput` anywhere and it is also not a global variable.

Assuming that the internal browser code assigns those variables itself, why cant I access `theInput` in a custom event handler?

```js
function submitHandler() {
  alert(theInput.value)
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="submitHandler(); return false">
  <input name="theInput">
</form>
```

In `submitHandler()`, `theInput` is undefined and the code breaks, as I expected.

Is there any documentation available about this? Could not find any, but it is admittedly something hard to search for. MDN docs even use this syntax in [one of their examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output#Example).

Comment: "onfoo" event handler functions are constructed as if they were in a series of `with` statements. It's primitive and weird and prone to all sorts of bizarre and confusing bugs, and that's a primary reason people recommend never using that method of attaching event handlers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inline handlers (unintuitively) appear to run inside a `with(this)`, where `this` is the element that the handler is on:

```html
<form onsubmit="debugger; console.log(theInput.value); return false">
  <input name="theInput">
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

[image]

The `document` is also `with`ed as well.

From a `<form>`, you can access an input with a particular name via dot notation, so referencing `theInput.value` works just like referencing `this.theInput.value` in the inline handler.

Solution: Never use inline handlers, they're crazy.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Unfortunately, Firefox doesnt display `with block`s in its dev tools, but I believe you. :P

Comment: @Blauhirn yes it's really confusing and as you have discovered not at all obvious what's going on. It seemed like a really cool idea in 1998 probably.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the browser is assigning `theInput` behind the scenes. The reason it's not working in your second case is because you're looking for `theInput` in the scope of the `submitHandler` function, not the scope of the actual event handler. It works if you pass `theInput` into `submitHandler` in your HTML `onsubmit`, even if you change the variable name in `submitHandler`.

```js
function submitHandler(input) {
  alert(input.value)
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="submitHandler(theInput); return false">
  <input name="theInput">
</form>
```

Furthermore, it fails if you change `submitHandler(theInput)` to something else, see below:

```js
function submitHandler(input) {
  alert(input.value)
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="submitHandler(myInput); return false">
  <input name="theInput">
</form>
```