# Create array of JavaScript objects from input form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a payment form and want to create an array of JS objects from the below HTML.   The objects would have the following structure:

```
var myObject = {
    merchantGuid: 'string value',
    accessToken: 'string value',
    active: boolean,
    url: 'string value'
};
```

The DOM would look like this:

```
<input type="hidden" data-active="false" name="tokenDatas[0].merchantGuid" value="abc1234" />
<input type="hidden" data-active="false" name="tokenDatas[0].accessToken" value="586b30a1" />
<input type="hidden" data-active="false" name="tokenDatas[0].active" value="false" />
<input type="hidden" data-active="false" name="tokenDatas[0].url" value="https://test.example.com/api" />

<input type="hidden" data-active="true" name="tokenDatas[1].merchantGuid" value="def6789" />
<input type="hidden" data-active="true" name="tokenDatas[1].accessToken" value="ca1v2d17" />
<input type="hidden" data-active="true" name="tokenDatas[1].active" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" data-active="true" name="tokenDatas[1].url" value="https://test.example.com/api" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery create object from form fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603117/jquery-create-object-from-form-fields)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this JS code.

```js
let fields = {};
    let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
      let data = inputs[i].getAttribute("name");
      fields[data] = data;
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" data-active="false" name="tokenDatas[0].merchantGuid" value="abc1234" />
<input type="hidden" data-active="false" name="tokenDatas[0].accessToken" value="586b30a1" />
<input type="hidden" data-active="false" name="tokenDatas[0].active" value="false" />
<input type="hidden" data-active="false" name="tokenDatas[0].url" value="https://test.example.com/api" />

<input type="hidden" data-active="true" name="tokenDatas[1].merchantGuid" value="def6789" />
<input type="hidden" data-active="true" name="tokenDatas[1].accessToken" value="ca1v2d17" />
<input type="hidden" data-active="true" name="tokenDatas[1].active" value="true" />
<input type="hidden" data-active="true" name="tokenDatas[1].url" value="https://test.example.com/api" />
```